# Print out environment variable

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I created an environment variable as follows:

```
setx HTTPS_PROXY "website"
```

And when I try to print it out:

```
echo %HTTPS_PROXY%
%HTTPS_PROXY%
```

Comment: `setx /?`: *Note: 2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool will be available in future command windows but not in the current CMD.exe command window.*

Answer (score 2):

[PetSerAl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840137/print-out-environment-variable#comment63141183_37840137) summarizes the reason from `setx /?`:

> ```
> NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.
>
>       2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
>          will be available in future command windows but not in the
>          current CMD.exe command window.
> …
> ```

Solution: you need to use [`SET` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), e.g. as follows.

```
set "HTTPS_PROXY=website"
setx HTTPS_PROXY "%HTTPS_PROXY%"
```

Note that (supposedly complex) `website` string is typed only once in above code snippet (to avoid a keying mistake) in so far that `%HTTPS_PROXY%` surely matches data in registry:

```
reg query hkcu\environment /V HTTPS_PROXY
```